# Swift: Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing a simple app and when I click to sign up the user, the app gets terminated. Please help me figure this out.

It says that:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key CreditCardTextField.'

Here's the error in more detail:

> 015-06-04 22:42:57.661 ParseStarterProject[43853:4461316] Unknown
>   class RegisterPageViewController in Interface Builder file. 2015-06-04
>   22:42:57.712 ParseStarterProject[43853:4461316] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   CreditCardTextField.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001106ccf35 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000011233ebb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00000001106ccb79 -[NSException raise] + 9   3   Foundation
>
>   0x0000000110b6b7b3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] +
>   259   4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110616e80
>   -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224  5   UIKit                               0x000000011134bc7d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506    6
>
>   UIKit                               0x00000001111aaf98
>   -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242   7   UIKit                               0x00000001111ab588 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109   8   UIKit
>
>   0x00000001111ab7f9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75    9
>
>   UIKit                               0x00000001111abc8e
>   -[UIViewController view] + 27     10  UIKit                               0x000000011174d41e -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController
>   _setPresentedViewController:] + 65    11  UIKit                               0x0000000111187429 -[UIPresentationController
>   initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 105  12 
>   UIKit                               0x00000001111b7a41
>   -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 1746     13  UIKit                               0x00000001111b9d81
>   __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 132     14 
>   UIKit                               0x00000001111b9ca5
>   -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 229  15  UIKit                               0x00000001110878be
>   -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75    16  UIKit                               0x000000011118e410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
>     17  UIKit                               0x000000011118d7df
>   -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522    18  UIKit                               0x00000001110cd308 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735  19  UIKit 
>   0x00000001110cdc33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683   20  UIKit
>
>   0x000000011109a9b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246  21  UIKit
>
>   0x00000001110a7a7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370    22
>   UIKit                               0x0000000111083103
>   _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961     23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110602551
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105f841d
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269   25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105f7a54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868     26  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001105f7486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470     27  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000113de79f0 GSEventRunModal + 161  28  UIKit
>   0x0000000111086420 UIApplicationMain + 1282   29  ParseStarterProject
>   0x000000010fbbe9de top_level_code + 78    30  ParseStarterProject
>   0x000000010fbbeaba main + 42  31  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000112b54145 start + 1  32  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]It seems that you have a bronken @IBOutlet for `CreditCardTextField`, check in your storyboard, as soon as you reconnect the outlet it all should work again

```
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key CreditCardTextField.'
```

This is how you check your outlets:

Select the field, the outlets in the right should be connect correctly and the circles in the code should have a dot inside, if not the connection is broken, control drag to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

NB. this can also happen in a Core Data app if the case of the property in the app code doesn't match a property in the momd. eg "launchPad" vs "launchpad"