# Swift: Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException after add array data to table

Tags: swift, tableview

After adapt data array to table, i get this error :
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
[image]
I read this question but it seem not be my answer.
[Swift: Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657629/swift-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception)

My storyboard like this:
[image]

And this is my code of tableview :

```
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var menuList = ["Row1", "Row2", "Row3", "Row4"]
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuList.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear   
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = menuList[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: Is the identifier of the cell set to `LabelCell` in Interface Builder?

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash. Then update your question with specific details about the crash (error message and point out the exact line causing the crash).

Comment: Thanks vadian ! i figure it.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion,  rmaddy !